WPF window keeps dwm border color
I am trying to make a WPF window that behaves exactly like a WinUI3 window (with ExtendsContentIntoTitleBar set) on Windows11. It should have a window border drawn by dwm that will show accent color if you check this in system settings

But it seems that after you customize WindowChrome to remove the standard win32 title bar, the border will no longer showing the accent color. The closest I can get is to leave a small margin in the ContentPresenter, something like 2 to leave some space to let the background dwm color showing a bit, but you can see it's actually not the border that's showing accent color, but the spacing I left inside, let alone I'd also have to patch the rounded corner in the content.
 <Style x:Key="MyWindowStyle" TargetType="local:MainWindow">
     <Setter Property="WindowChrome.WindowChrome">
         <Setter.Value>
<!-- Setting GlassFrameThickness to 0 you get a very pixelated rough rounded corner -->
             <WindowChrome
                 CaptionHeight="100"
                 GlassFrameThickness="-1"  
                 UseAeroCaptionButtons="False" />
         </Setter.Value>
     </Setter>
     <Setter Property="Template">
         <Setter.Value>
             <ControlTemplate TargetType="local:MainWindow">
                 <ContentPresenter Margin="2" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" />
             </ControlTemplate>
         </Setter.Value>
     </Setter>
 </Style>




State
WinUI3
WPF




Active




Inactive





